# Sidekiq's perform_in never actually performs, although it's showing as "busy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have simply created a worker to restart apache in the background, since doing it inside of the rails app just freezes the app and throws a "Internal Server Error"

I am doing something *extremely* simple.

Here's my worker:

```
# app/workers/reload_apache_worker.rb
class ReloadApacheWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 graceful`
  end
end
```

And I am simply calling it with `ReloadApacheWorker.perform_in(5.seconds)`

Nothing happens. I can see in the sidekiq web interface that it is "busy".
[image]

What am I doing wrong? My other 2 workers that I execute with `.perform_async` are working flawlessly, so I'm not sure what's up with this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you restart the server during (inside) the request you'll get an error as it won't respond to it, thus you get an error.

Comment: Isn't reloading the Apache configuration from a Sidekiq worker doing it "outside" (as a background task) though?

Comment: Yes, using a background worker it should work. I would try to check sidekiq/apache logs to see if the restart command is working as intended. Also, make sure sidekiq doesn't rely on the apache (I believe it doesn't).